# How to return an element state using jQuery's toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

How alert message when toggle is closed.

this toggle works but not alert.

script:

```
$( "#btn-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( "#btn-container-all" ).toggle( "slow" );
  var isHidden = $('#btn-container-all').is(":hidden");
   if(isHidden)  { 
     alert('closed');   
  }
});
```

html:

```
<input type="button" id="btn-toggle" value="list"  />
    <div id="btn-container-all"> //codes... </div>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle recreating the issue please

Comment: @RUJordan the issue is clearly visible without the fiddle.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if it was clearly visible the OP wouldn't have posted the question ;)

Comment: here jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3R8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a callback function for that cause:
 ***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EhucOrU/2/edit)***

```
$( "#btn-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( "#btn-container-all" ).toggle( "slow", function(){
      var isHidden = $(this).is(":hidden");
      if(isHidden)  { 
          alert('closed');  
      }
  });
});
```

also don't forget about the `this` keyword

---

If you want to create a generic function to test more elements under different circumstances so you don't need to repeat-yourself:
***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EhucOrU/4/edit)***

```
function isElementClosed(){
  if($(this).is(":hidden")){
    alert('closed');
  }
}

$( "#btn-toggle" ).click(function() {
   $( "#btn-container-all" ).toggle( "slow", isElementClosed);
});
```

Comment: **+1** Wow, I didn't post quick enough, I had the exact same answer (now deleted) :)

Comment: fast answer. Thank @Roko C. Buljan works fine.I accept your answer.